# Shorten timestamp appearing rate to 5 minutes

Tags: feature-request, chat, timestamps

In chat, there is a timestamp on the right that appears every six posts and every fifteen minutes. However, it is my opinion that the time-based timestamp should appear given a shorter timespan, say five minutes. This time value is flexible, but I think 5 is a good number for this.

Comment: Can you give a reason why you're requesting this? We've toyed with several values until we came up with the current ones, and 15 minutes still seems like a good compromise between noise level and accuracy. "it is my opinion that [it should be] a shorter timespan" isn't really an argument in itself.

Comment: Good point. I think often chat topics change fast enough that a decreased time is necessary for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, this is already [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), based on the following rules for timestamp display (which balpha or Marc may need to correct me on):

1. A timestamp will appear at most once per monologue (the box that surrounds your individual messages)
2. A timestamp will appear on at least every sixth monologue
3. A timestamp will appear after fifteen minutes has elapsed since the previous timestamp

Comment: OK, I've rephrased the question. Thanks for your answer. :)